# Does a provisioning profiles expiry date depend on the linked certificates date?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, iphone-developer-program

I have an enterprise account and I'm using two provisioning profiles for two apps.

Today I had go through the member centre and I found that Production certificate is going to expire on Jun 01 2017, but the two distribution profiles which I used in apps (profiles linked with certificates) are going to expire.

One profile expired yesterday and another profile is going to expire tomorrow. 
For both the profiles status is ACTIVE and green mark is there.

So what do I have to do now? Can you use those profiles upto 2017 without any issue? Or do I have to create new profiles. I am using enterprise distribution not app store distribution.

Comment: No, you can't have a provisioning profile for more than 1 year expiry time; you have to renew it from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

**It will not affect the app which is live on store.**

But if you upload new version then you have to generate new production certificate and assign this certificate to your provisioning profiles.

Answer (score 0):

The profile has an expiry of 1 year. But if you release a app with a profile and the profile expires **there will be no effect on the app in the store**.

You don't need to create a new profile. Just click edit and save. It will get an extended expiry date.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But actually the app was not released to app store. The app is distribute within enterprise.

Comment: ok that time we no need to create one more build for distribution ?

Comment: @NareshG > Yes. You don't have to create another profile.

Comment: Rashad I am asking wether I have to create another ipa file with new profiles (extended validity). Or old ipa files will work automatically.

Comment: Otherwise is there any way to install only profiles from server instead of install new ipa file.

Comment: @NareshG > No you don't need to create a new ipa file.old one will work. Sorry I was out of office.. :D

Comment: But actual issue is after extend expire date also the app was not working due to that reason it force me to create new ipa files again.Total 6 apps builds i recreated.